# C/C++ Getting timestamp with time zone offset info

Tags: c++, c

I need to get timestamp in the following format that includes the timezone offset from UTC:

2014-03-07T10:03:50+**02:00**

I'm trying this approach but getting it as UTC without the timezone info formatted correctly:

```
time_t now;
time(&now);
char ts[sizeof "1970-01-01T00:00:00+00:00"];
strftime(ts, sizeof ts, "%FT%T%z", gmtime(&now));
printf("Timestamp: %s\n\n", ts);
```

And this is the result:

2014-03-07T09:29:40+**0200**

Comment: have you tried localtime instead of gmtime?

Comment: @Myforwik `localtime` is local time, what if he lives in a different time zone?

Comment: Yes, I tried both, I'm trying to get the colon between the timezone offset hours and minutes like 02:00 instead of 0200

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just insert a colon after calling strftime?

Answer (score 1):

[Man 7 strftime](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) formats the time `tm` according to the format specification format. And one of the format `%z` outputs the numeric timezone by default as `hhmm` without colon `:` between hours and minutes,

`%z` : The `+hhmm` or `-hhmm` numeric timezone (that is, the hour and minute offset from UTC). (SU)